# How to make a convert set in list to row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

original df

```
list1 = ['apple','lemon']
list2 = [[('taste','sweet'),('sweetness','5')],[('taste','sour'),('sweetness','0')]]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list1,list2)), columns=['fruit', 'description'])
df.head()
```

desired output

```
list3 = ['apple','lemon']
list4 = ['sweet','sour']
list5 = ['5','0']

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list3,list4,list5)), columns=['fruit', 'taste', 'sweetness'])
df2.head()
```

what had i tried, but this seem 'weird', by trying to remove punctuation one by one, then only convert to row

```
df['description'] = df['description'].astype(str)
df['description'] = df['description'].str[1:-1]
df['description'] = df['description'].str.replace("(","")
df.head()
```

is there a better way to convert the list to desired row and column?
Thanks

Comment: there isnt a very sour in df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionaries from tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column, last append to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
L = [dict(y) for y in df.pop('description')]
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index))
print (df)
   fruit      taste sweetness
0  apple      sweet         5
1  lemon       sour         0
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could build it straight from `list1` and `list2` instead of working backwards from the `description`... eg: `pd.DataFrame({'fruit': f, **dict(v)} for f, v in zip(list1, list2))`